# I'm looking to have this API response automatically populate into an html div

Tags: python, html

I wrote this page to essentially create a GUI that assists with football research i want to do via the college football API. I have acquired my bearer key, and have gotten my scripts to return values, however i'm not sure how to get the response to automatically populate in a div tag. Ive looked into Flask and localhost, but am unsure where to go from here, as im returning the desired json libraries when the scripts are run on their own.

```
from cfbd.models import team
from cfbd.api.players_api import PlayersApi
import cfbd
import json

#access key
configuration = cfbd.Configuration()
configuration.api_key['Authorization'] = 'MY_ACCESS_KEY_HERE'
configuration.api_key_prefix['Authorization'] = 'Bearer'


#player search parameter
search_term = "Deonte Banks"

#processes the request and prints the data of an individual player and their background
api_instance = cfbd.PlayersApi(cfbd.ApiClient(configuration))
response = api_instance.player_search(search_term = search_term)
print(response)
```

//this script returns the desired information, in the following format.

```
[{'first_name': 'Deonte',
 'height': 74,
 'hometown': 'Edgewood, MD',
 'id': 4428328,
 'jersey': 3,
 'last_name': 'Banks',
 'name': 'Deonte Banks',
 'position': 'DB',
 'team': 'Maryland',
 'team_color': '#D5002B',
 'team_color_secondary': '#ffcd00',
 'weight': 205}]
```

However, in the final code block below, i have been unable to integrate this process with html/css, and receive an error. So far i have experimented with mainly localhost, Please let me know if anyone knows how to fix.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>
        BAAL Sports
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.1.1/core.css" />
<script type="module" src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.1.1/core.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
    #mytext{
        color:aqua;
        font-size: 100px;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <form id="myForm">
        <label for="firstNameInput">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="firstNameInput" name="firstNameInput">
        
        <label for="lastNameInput">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="lastNameInput" name="lastNameInput">

        <button type="button" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        function submitForm() {
            // Get values from the text inputs
            var firstName = document.getElementById('firstNameInput').value;
            var lastName = document.getElementById('lastNameInput').value;

            // Construct the API endpoint using the fetched values
            var apiEndpoint = `https://api.collegefootballdata.com/player/search?searchTerm=${firstName}%20${lastName}`;

            // Log the constructed API endpoint
            console.log('API Endpoint:', apiEndpoint);

            // Perform the API call with the constructed endpoint
            fetch(apiEndpoint)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    // Do something with the API response data
                    console.log('API Response:', data);
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

have tried flask, and using python -m http.server 3000 in the command console, and then used the corresponding port on the html page, but was still unsuccessful, and received the following messages, which i am unable to understand.

```
Serving HTTP on :: port 3000 (http://[::]:3000/) ...
::1 - - [29/Jan/2024 17:02:54] "GET /webcode.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [29/Jan/2024 17:02:54] code 404, message File not found
::1 - - [29/Jan/2024 17:02:54] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: If you're returning JSON to the client, you can use a DataTables library to convert that to an HTML table. There's nothing built-in that does it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to asynchronously load it after a request in the current page, I strongly recommend that you use htmx. I do not recommend using pyscript, the last time I checked it wasn't very stable and still not very much optimized (it's python, after all).

HTMX is a JS library that enables you to make requests and control interface elements with the response.

```
<div>
    <form hx-post="/your_endpoint" hx-target="#result" hx-swap="innerHTML">
      <button type="submit">Get football data</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="result">
    <!-- response will be rendered here -->
  </div>
```

notice that in `/your_endpoint` you will make the request to the API, handle it as necessary and then return the HTML to the client.

Please let me know if this answer is helpful :)

Comment: This answer was massively helpful, thank you! Although i am not completly done yet, as i am now returning a failed to fetch error. from my research, i believe it has top do with the access allow control origin, and am wondering if it potentially has to do with not including my bearer key in the updated script. let me know if you have anymore leads, and if not no worries, thank you again :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :) about the CORS, I'd need more details to help. If the response was forbidden or unauthorized, check your keys and if the server accepts requests from localhost (if you're running locally) or from your own server if you have one.